# How to install Android Emulator in VSCode without installing the Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

I've read some references that can install and execute Android Emulator in VScode without installing Android Studio.

But I didn't success in installing, if you are familiar

Is there any way I can run an emulator on visual studio code without android studio's help?

Answer (score 0):

You can install Android SDK Commandline Tool only. Check out this gist [gist](https://gist.github.com/Try-Parser/b7106d941cc9b1c9e7b4c7443a7c3540)

Comment: Thank you. I am following your gist guide already, but not succeed yet.
An issue occured in stage - Checking list of device